# Why the first span goes in the bottom of the second one when they don't have identical height?

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```css
.one{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.two{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="one"> Explanation: </span>
<span class="two">There is some explanation about something. There is some explanation about something</span>
```

As you see, the word of `EXPLANATION` is in the bottom of `.two` box. How can I keep it in the top of that? Here is expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vertical-align: top;` to the rescue!

```css
.one{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.two{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<span class="one"> Explanation: </span>
<span class="two">There is some explanation about something. There is some explanation about something</span>
```

Comment: Just one thing, what's the difference between `top` and `text-top` as the value of `vertical-align` property?

Comment: @MartinAJ just google it :) top: "Align the top of the element and its descendants with the top of the entire line.", text-top: "Aligns the top of the element with the top of the parent element's font." From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Answer (score 2):

The vertical align property has a default value of `baseline`, thats why the first span gets to view on the baseline since the next span has a bigger height.

In order to make it view on top you need to set the `vertical-align` property to top:

```
.one{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`span` is an `inline` element having `vertical-align: baseline` by default.

Add `vertical-align: top` to override it.

```css
.one {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.two {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<span class="one"> Explanation: </span>
<span class="two">There is some explanation about something. There is some explanation about something</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vertical-align: top;`

Here an [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/12/css-baseline-the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugl) explaining CSS default base line.

```
.one{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default all `inline` and `inline-block` elements are aligned according to the `baseline` of parent element.

From [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)):

> The baseline is the line upon which most letters "sit" and below which descenders extend.

[image]

To fix this you can use `vertical-align: top` with `display: inline-block` explicitly.

```css
.one,
.two {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.one {
  width: 80px;
}

.two {
  width: 100px;      
}
```

```html
<span class="one"> Explanation: </span>
<span class="two">There is some explanation about something. There is some explanation about something</span>
```